# How to use contextFactory.setKeyStorePath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ssl, jetty

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 64 bit, Eclipse 3.8.1 and embedded Jetty 9.3.12 to run a WebSocket server

I wish to convert to use secure websockets and am trying to use

```
SslContextFactory contextFactory = new SslContextFactory(); 
contextFactory.setKeyStorePath("./keystore");
```

I do not know where to place the keystore file inside Ubuntu so that the above works. In other words: I do not know what `./keystore` should read

I tried some tests using

```
Resource keystore = 
    Resource.newClassPathResource("/WebSocketTest/certificate/jetty.key");

if (keystore != null) {
    System.out.println("keystore found");
}
```

And this shows that I cannot find the `/WebSocketTest/certificate/jetty.key`

`certificate` is a linked resource I added that points to `/opt/jetty/etc`
and contains the `jetty.key` file

There are NO filters on the resources

Can someone please explain to me how to correctly define the location of the keystore

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of questions here:

Where is the working directory? You can find that out by doing a

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

In an Eclipse-project this is in general the project-folder, in your case `WebSocketTest`

So a way to create the resource could be

```
Resource keystore = Resource.newResource(new File("./certificate/jetty.key"));
```

You can keep it with `newClassPathResource` if you make sure that the directory and its files are copied to the class-output-directory (putting the certificates-directory into the source-folder should do the trick. The advantage of this approach would be that you don't need to change anything, if you export the project as jar and the file isn't available directly via File anymore.